# url regex, test for directory (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var url = 'http://www.domain.com/folderX/';

if(url == 'folderX') {
   //do this
} else {
   //do that
}
```

but, it **should not** matter if the url is presented as:

1) http://www.domain.com/folderX/

2) www.domain.com/folderX/

3) domain.com/folderX/

I just want to test whether or not it is "folderX"

Comment: What about `/path/to/folderX`?

Comment: what if it's `http://www.domain.com/someOtherfolderX/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var folder = (function() {
  var href = window.location.href;
  if(href.lastIndexOf('/') === href.length - 1) { //strip out trailing "/"
     href = href.substring(0, href.length - 1);
  }
  var slashes = href.split('/');
  return slashes[slashes.length - 1];
})();

if(folder === 'folderX') {
   //do something...
}
```